fantasy/adventure character obsessed with birds
I watched a movie, perhaps fifteen years or more ago, that was a fantasy/adventure where the party of adventurers were followed and antagonized by an evil being. One character was obsessed with birds, and, no matter how dire the party's situation, whenever he'd see a bird, he would become distracted by it and instantly chase after it. At the end of the movie, the evil force was transformed into a crow and the obsessed character snatched up the crow and ate it, thereby ending the evil. Any ideas?

That would be The Spiderwick Chronicles (2008), based on the book series. (though it's only 6 years old)
Hogsqueal is an unintelligent bird-eating hobgoblin who seeks revenge against Mulgarath for killing his family. Hogsqueal is easily distracted by birds, which is a favorite delicacy of his. When he sees one, he forgets what he is doing and is not much help. 
He certainly comes in handy at the end of movie when on the roof, Jared throws the titular Spiderwick field guide book onto the lawn; as Mulgarath transforms into a raven to catch it, he is snatched and eaten by Hogsqueal.

This looks the catch to me +1.
